# Stimulsoft MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.1, stimulsoft

The using directive could not find the Stimulsoft Assembly.

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using NursingHomeStock.Resources
@using Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = GlobalResources.Reports;
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewerFx(new StiMvcViewerFxOptions
{
    ActionGetReportSnapshot = "GetStatsForNursingHome",
    ActionGetLocalization = "GetLocalization",
    ActionExportReport = "ExportReport",
    Width = Unit.Percentage(100),
    Height = Unit.Pixel(600),
    Zoom = 75
})
```

When I am Setting the Embed Interop Types Attribute to true then the assembly could be found but at compile time I get following error:

```
Error   1   Cannot embed interop types from assembly 'c:\svn\lib\Stimulsoft\2013.3.1800\Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc.dll' because it is missing either the 'ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute' attribute or the 'PrimaryInteropAssemblyAttribute' attribute c:\svn\lib\Stimulsoft\2013.3.1800\Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc.dll NursingHomeStock
```

I have referenced follwoing Assemblies:

- Stimulsoft.Base
- Stimulsoft.Report
- Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc

Am I missing a reference?

I am using MVC5.1

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Assembly Attribute CopyLocal => true